# Why do this query takes more than 180 secs to run?

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE TABLE `tvnotif` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `pingId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `token` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `summary` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `startTime` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `endTime` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `processed` int(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `created` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `modified` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `processedIndex` (`processed`),
  KEY `summaryIndex` (`summary`),
  KEY `tokenIndex` (`token`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=18297898 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;
```

```
CREATE TABLE `vv_us` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `athleteid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `token` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `secret` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `active` int(1) DEFAULT '1',
  `created` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `modified` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `type` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT 'mc',
  `step` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `host` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `server` mediumblob,
  `tempcreds` mediumblob,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `activeIndex` (`active`),
  KEY `typeIndex` (`type`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=33888 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;
```

I am running a query which is mostly based on the table tvnotif which has at least 2 million rows of data in it, all the other tables are having less amount only. I added the index for the tables before that the query took 20 minutes to run and now its taking 160 secs.

```
EXPLAIN SELECT tvu.secret,COALESCE(php_timezone,"America/Los_Angeles") AS userTz,tn.*,tvu.athleteid,tvu.type FROM tvnotif AS tn 
            LEFT JOIN vv_us AS tvu ON  tvu.token = tn.token
            LEFT JOIN tbl_ath_pro AS tap ON tap.athleteid = tvu.athleteid
            LEFT JOIN timezones AS tz ON tz.tz_id = tap.tz_id
            WHERE tvu.active = 1 AND tn.summary = 'dailies' AND tn.processed = 0
            LIMIT 300
```

[image]

Comment: Just to observe... `LEFT JOIN tvu...WHERE tvu.active =` is the same as `INNER JOIN tvu` and `active` int(1)` (and `processed`) might be more usefully represented as `TINYINT()`

Comment: How many rows of your 2 million rows have `tn.processed = 0` and how many of those have `tvu.active = 0`? How relevant is your `order by rand()`? The join currently internally generates 14 million rows, order them by rand, then throws away 13999700 of them, so if you cannot use different indexes, redefining/weakening your rand might be a way to tackle your problem too.

Comment: Even if the rand() is not there its taking time to run , if rand() is there then an extra 30 seconds more. @Solarflare

Answer (score 2):

The problem is probably your indexes... You have indexes on each field individually.  What you need is a composite index on ALL 3 parts as a single index.  Without, it can't pick the best one as you have 3 parts of the where clause.

Build a SINGLE index on ( processed, summary, token )

This way the query can jump directly to the processed records, directly to the summary value and then get those records and be done.

Additionally, your VV_US table should have an index on ( token, active ) so the join will be optimized on BOTH parts.

Comment: Should I delete the other individual indexes or can I keep them and add a new one with these three?  @DRapp

Comment: Depends on if you will need them on other queries that cannot utilize the composite one.  But indexes should be based on the most likely querying components (even if multiple) as a single index vs multiple individual.  Add as NEEDED when query is slow, but in this case, yes, remove the other 3 individuals.